# Get error when using CASE statement with GROUP BY in Hive

Tags: sql, group-by, apache-spark-sql, hive

I have data like

| user_id | status | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | active | John |
| 11111 | rejected | Jai |
| 22222 | active | Prince |
| 33333 | rejected | King |

I want output as

| user_id | active_name | rejected_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | John | Jai |
| 22222 | Prince | null |
| 33333 | null | King |

i.e. aggregate on user_id and get names based on status

I do

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    CASE WHEN status = 'active' THEN name ELSE NULL END AS active_name,
    CASE WHEN status = 'rejected' THEN name ELSE NULL END AS rejected_name
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
```

But this throws an error. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need aggregation functions for every column that is not in the GROUP BY

For you `MAX` is the right choice, but of course there many others for man occations

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'active' THEN name ELSE NULL END) AS active_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'rejected' THEN name ELSE NULL END) AS rejected_name
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
```